# Mounting an Azure file share using Cloudstor on a local Docker container

Tags: azure, docker, mount, azure-storage

I'm developing a docker image that requires access to shared data in a Azure file share.  I want to test this locally before deploying to Azure and I'm not using swarms.

I'm using the [Azure CloudStor Docker plugin](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-azure/persistent-data-volumes/)

I've successfully installed the Cloudstor plugin locally:

```
docker plugin install --alias cloudstor:azure --grant-all-permissions docker4x/cloudstor:17.06.1-ce-azure1 CLOUD_PLATFORM=AZURE AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY="..." AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT="..."
```

And successfully compiled my container using a Docker file:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-base-ubuntu18.04

# Update + Prerequisites
RUN apt-get update \    
    && apt-get -y install build-essential checkinstall \
    && apt-get -y install sudo \
    && apt-get -y install curl \
    && apt-get -y install zip \
    && apt-get -y install unzip \
    && apt-get -y install cifs-utils \    
    && apt-get -y install nfs-common nfs-kernel-server

# Install Azure CLI
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash

# SMB ports
EXPOSE 137/udp 138/udp 139 445

RUN mkdir /mnt/myshare
```

If I run the container without --mount everything works fine.

If I however try this:

```
docker run -it myImage --mount type=volume,volume-driver=cloudstor:azure,source="myAzureShare",destination="/mnt/myShare" /bin/bash
```

I get this error:

> docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"--mount\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Do I need to install any CloudStor dependencies in the image?  Are there any extra parameters I need to add when running the container?

**Edit:**  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34503625/796634) fixed the above error.  But now it's as though Docker can't find the image when i use the  --mount flag:

> docker.exe: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for
>   myImage, repository does not exist or may require 'docker
>   login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.

If I don't use --mount the image loads fine

Answer (score 1):

Mounting an Azure file share using Cloudstor on a local Docker container

You can try "Docker Volume Driver for Azure File Storage",it uses SMB as well CIFS protocols for file share.
Here you can find source code - https://github.com/Azure/azurefile-dockervolumedriver
CloudStor Docker plugin is well suitable for AWS.

Even by using YAML template you can mount a volume in a container group where all containers in the group can access.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files

Comment: Thanks, I'd rather not use the Volume Docker Driver as it's not supported any more and superseded by the Cloudstor plugin.  Cloudstor seems to be the best option but want to get it working locally

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't do this right now:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/38842
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39460

One issue is unresolved and the other is due to ClodStor using SMB 2.1 but SMB 3.0 is required for local installation.